# Debugging error: DFS(Depth First Search) Graph, ADT

Tags: c, algorithm, adt, depth-first-search

I'm a beginner of studying Graph in ADT, C language.

This is the code that debug had captured. The problem code is `if(pg>visitInfo[visitV] == 0)` from ALGraphDFS.c
And Debug program said that upper code occurs error on these call sequences.

```
DFShowGraphVertex(&graph, A); printf("\n") (main code)
VisitVertex(pg, visitV);
if (pg->visitInfo[visitV] == 0)....
```

I couldn't understand why this was the error. Because I used `enum {A,B,C...}` and make visitInfo array by using this code.

```
pg->visitInfo = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * pg->numV);
memset(pg->visitInfo, 0, sizeof(int) * pg->numV);
```

(numV means the number of vertex in DFS. And pg means struct _ual)

Would you help me to find the problem on this code? It will be very helpful for me. Total codes for DFS are under this line.

Thank you

P.S. These codes are in the book named `Introduction to Data Structures Using C` for studying ADT.

Filename: `ALGraphDFS.h / DLinkedList.h / ArrayBaseStack.h / ALGraphDFS.c / DLinkedList.c / ArrayBaseStack.c / DFSMain.c`

[ALGraphDFS.h]

```
#ifndef __AL_GRAPH_DFS__
#define __AL_GRAPH_DFS__

#include "DLinkedList.h"

enum {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J};

typedef struct _ual {
    int numV;
    int numE;
    List * adjList;
    int * visitInfo;
} ALGraph;

void GraphInit(ALGraph * pg, int nv);

void GraphDestroy(ALGraph * pg);

void AddEdge(ALGraph * pg, int fromV, int toV);

void ShowGraphEdgeInfo(ALGraph * pg);

void DFShowGraphVertex(ALGraph * pg, int startV);

#endif
```

[DLinkedList.h]

```
#ifndef __D_LINKED_LIST_H__
#define __D_LINKED_LIST_H__

#define TRUE    1
#define FALSE   0

typedef int LData;

typedef struct _node {
    LData data;
    struct _node * next;
} Node;

typedef struct _linkedList {
    Node * head;
    Node * cur;
    Node * before;
    int numOfData;
    int(*comp)(LData d1, LData d2);
} LinkedList;

typedef LinkedList List;

void ListInit(List * plist);
void LInsert(List * plist, LData data);

int LFirst(List * plist, LData * pdata);
int LNext(List * plist, LData * pdata);

LData LRemove(List * plist);
int LCount(List * plist);

void SetSortRule(List * plist, int(*comp)(LData d1, LData d2));

#endif
```

[ArrayBaseStack.h]

```
#ifndef __AB_STACK_H__
#define __AB_STACK_H__

#define TRUE    1
#define FALSE   0
#define STACK_LEN   100

typedef int Data;

typedef struct _arrayStack {
    Data stackArr[STACK_LEN];
    int topIndex;
} ArrayStack;

typedef ArrayStack Stack;

void StackInit(Stack * pstack);
int SIsEmpty(Stack * pstack);

void SPush(Stack * pstack, Data data);
Data SPop(Stack * pstack);
Data SPeek(Stack * pstack);

#endif
```

[ALGraphDFS.c]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "ALGraphDFS.h"
#include "DLinkedList.h"
#include "ArrayBaseStack.h"

int WhoIsPrecede(int data1, int data2);

void GraphInit(ALGraph * pg, int nv) {
    int i;

    pg->adjList = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List) * nv);
    pg->numV = nv;
    pg->numE = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < nv; i++) {
        ListInit(&(pg->adjList[i]));
        SetSortRule(&(pg->adjList[i]), WhoIsPrecede);
    }

    pg->visitInfo = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * pg->numV);
    memset(pg->visitInfo, 0, sizeof(int) * pg->numV);

}

void GraphDestroy(ALGraph * pg) {
    if (pg->adjList != NULL)
        free(pg->adjList);

    if (pg->visitInfo != NULL)
        free(pg->visitInfo);
}

void AddEdge(ALGraph * pg, int fromV, int toV) {
    LInsert(&(pg->adjList[fromV]), toV);
    LInsert(&(pg->adjList[toV]), fromV);
    pg->numE += 1;
}

void ShowGraphEdgeInfo(ALGraph * pg) {
    int i;
    int vx;

    for (i = 0; i < pg->numV; i++) {
        printf("Connected %c: ", i + 65);
        if (LFirst(&(pg->adjList[i]), &vx)) {
            printf("%c ", vx + 65);
            while (LNext(&(pg->adjList[i]), &vx))
                printf("%c ", vx + 65);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}

int VisitVertex(ALGraph * pg, int visitV) {
    if (pg->visitInfo[visitV] == 0) {
        pg->visitInfo[visitV] = 1;
        printf("%c ", visitV + 65);
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}

void DFShowGraphVertex(ALGraph * pg, int startV) {
    Stack stack;
    int visitV = startV;
    int nextV;

    StackInit(&stack);
    VisitVertex(pg, visitV);
    SPush(&stack, visitV);

    while (LFirst(&(pg->adjList[visitV]), &nextV) == TRUE) {
        int visitFlag = FALSE;

        if (VisitVertex(pg, nextV) == TRUE) {
            SPush(&stack, visitV);
            visitV = nextV;
            visitFlag = TRUE;
        }
        else {
            while (LNext(&(pg->adjList[visitV]), &nextV) == TRUE) {
                if (VisitVertex(pg, nextV) == TRUE) {
                    SPush(&stack, visitV);
                    visitV = nextV;
                    visitFlag = TRUE;

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (visitFlag == FALSE) {
            if (SIsEmpty(&stack) == TRUE)
                break;
            else
                visitV = SPop(&stack);
        }
    }
    memset(pg->visitInfo, 0, sizeof(int) * pg->numV);
}    

int WhoIsPrecede(int data1, int data2) {
    if (data1 < data2)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

[DLinkedList.c]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "DLinkedList.h"

void ListInit(List * plist) {
    plist->head = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    plist->head->next = NULL;
    plist->comp = NULL;
    plist->numOfData = 0;
}

void FInsert(List * plist, LData data) {
    Node * newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->data = data;

    newNode->next = plist->head->next;
    plist->head = newNode;

    (plist->numOfData)++;
}

void SInsert(List * plist, LData data) {
    Node * newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    Node * pred = plist->head;
    newNode->data = data;

    while (pred->next != NULL && plist->comp(data, pred->next->data) != 0) {
        pred = pred->next;
    }

    newNode->next = pred->next;
    pred->next = newNode;

    (plist->numOfData)++;
}

void LInsert(List * plist, LData data) {
    if (plist->comp == NULL)
        FInsert(plist, data);
    else
        SInsert(plist, data);
}

int LFirst(List * plist, LData * pdata) {
    if (plist->head->next == NULL)
        return FALSE;

        plist->before = plist->head;
        plist->cur = plist->head->next;

        *pdata = plist->head->data;
        return TRUE;
    }

    int LNext(List * plist, LData * pdata) {
        if (plist->cur->next == NULL)
            return FALSE;

    plist->before = plist->cur;
    plist->cur = plist->cur->next;

    *pdata = plist->cur->data;
    return TRUE;
}    

LData LRemove(List * plist) {
    Node * rpos = plist->cur;
    LData rdata = rpos->data;

    plist->before->next = plist->cur->next;
    plist->cur = plist->before;

    free(rpos);
    (plist->numOfData)--;
    return rdata;
}

int LCount(List * plist) {
    return plist->numOfData;
}

void SetSortRule(List * plist, int(*comp)(LData d1, LData d2)) {
    plist->comp = comp;
}
```

[ArrayBaseStack.c]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "ArrayBaseStack.h"

void StackInit(Stack * pstack) {
    pstack->topIndex = -1;
}

int SIsEmpty(Stack * pstack) {
    if (pstack->topIndex == -1)
        return TRUE;
    else
        return FALSE;
}

void SPush(Stack * pstack, Data data) {
    pstack->topIndex += 1;
    pstack->stackArr[pstack->topIndex] = data;
}

Data SPop(Stack * pstack) {
    int rIdx;

    if (SIsEmpty(pstack)) {
        printf("Error! \n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    rIdx = pstack->topIndex;
    pstack->topIndex -= 1;

    return pstack->stackArr[rIdx];
}

Data SPeek(Stack * pstack) {
    if (SIsEmpty(pstack)) {
        printf("Error! \n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    return pstack->stackArr[pstack->topIndex];
}
```

[DFSMain.c]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ALGraphDFS.h"

int main(void) {
    ALGraph graph;
    GraphInit(&graph, 7);

    AddEdge(&graph, A, B);
    AddEdge(&graph, A, D);
    AddEdge(&graph, B, C);
    AddEdge(&graph, D, C);
    AddEdge(&graph, D, E);
    AddEdge(&graph, E, F);
    AddEdge(&graph, E, G);

    ShowGraphEdgeInfo(&graph);

    DFShowGraphVertex(&graph, A); printf("\n");
    DFShowGraphVertex(&graph, C); printf("\n");
    DFShowGraphVertex(&graph, E); printf("\n");
    DFShowGraphVertex(&graph, G); printf("\n");

    GraphDestroy(&graph);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should really mention the actual error you get.

Comment: Error message: Exception throw: read access violation
pg->visitInfo was 0x3AC2371E.

Comment: int VisitVertex(ALGraph * pg, int visitV) {
    if (pg->visitInfo[visitV] == 0) {
        pg->visitInfo[visitV] = 1;
        printf("%c ", visitV + 65);
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
} on [ALGraphDFS.c]. Exception throw Error occurs at if(pg->visitInfo[visitV] == 0)

Answer (score 2):

```
void ListInit(List * plist) {
plist->head = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
plist->head->next = NULL;
plist->comp = NULL;
plist->numOfData = 0;
}
```

You never initialize `plist->data` here which is garbage.When you call `DFShowGraphVertex()`,

```
while (LFirst(&(pg->adjList[visitV]), &nextV) == TRUE) {
    int visitFlag = FALSE;
    if (VisitVertex(pg, nextV) == TRUE) {
```

In call to `VisitVertex` `nextV` holds that garbage, because `LFirst` just returns the first node.

EDIT: If you are treating the first node in each adjacency list as dummy node, then `LFirst()` should begin from second node. A better approach would be to not have dummy node at all.

Comment: I solve the problem. The problem was about *pdata on LFirst. Thanks!